# Как соединить программу на ассемблере с программой на C?

Tags: c, ассемблер

Есть программа для линукс, которая содержит функцию для вывода одной буквы в консоль:

```
global test

section .data
msg db 0xD0, 0xBF, 10
msg_len equ $-msg

section .text
test:   push ebp
        mov ebp, esp

        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, msg
        mov edx, msg_len
        int 80h

        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 80h

        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
```

И программа на C, которая пытается вызвать подпрограмму test:

```
extern void test();

int main(){
        test();
}
```

Компиляция второго кода:

```
   gcc main.cpp -c -m32
```

Выходит 2 объектных файла, которые я пытаюсь слинковать в исполняемый файл:

```
gcc main.o file.o -m32
```

Ответ:

> main.o: In function `main':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to`test()'

Подскажите пожалуйста - как правильно поступить, чтобы получился исполняемый файл

**EDIT**
Проблема решена - я компилировал код не на C, а на C++ и редактор связей не мог найти символ. Проблема решилась добавлением extern "C" в код на C++

Comment: @Abyx готово, поправил

Comment: @sddvxd и чё заработало?

Comment: @Dmitriy нет, не линкуется так-же

Comment: Разберись с манглингом имен. Посмотри, как выглядит символ test в объектном файле на асме и какой символ ожидает линкер.

Comment: @typemoon readelf выводит, что test в объектном файле не имеет типа, тогда как функция main в объектном файле C имеет тип FUNCTION. Инструкцию к NASM нашел, но добавление hashlookup:function после global не помогает - ситуация та-же

Comment: А не проще сделать ассемблер вставку в сишку через `__assembly__ {...}`? Хотя может я и упускаю что-то, но возможно и вы упускаете к примеру аргументы.

Comment: Кстати, есть еще такая штука оператор [asm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/asm) советую изучить. Мы можем собирать инструкции из строк, например собранные или переданные через функции.

Comment: `gcc -x c main.cpp -c -m32` или `gcc main.c -c -m32`. И не надо вам плюсы.